# SQL Server. Join/Pivot/Performance help please

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, join, pivot

I've created this view that is painfully slow to query and creating performance issues. I think I need to utilize PIVOT but I can't really wrap my head around it...

Here's what I've got currently.

```
select
    p.instrumentsettingsid,
    sum(case when p1.id is null then 0 else 1 end) as 'Cash',
    sum(case when p2.id is null then 0 else 1 end) as HighInterest,
    sum(case when p3.id is null then 0 else 1 end) as 'ML Loan',
    sum(case when p4.id is null then 0 else 1 end) as 'Investment Note',
    sum(case when p5.id is null then 0 else 1 end) as 'Trading',
    sum(case when p6.id is null then 0 else 1 end) as 'DD Trading',
    sum(case when p7.id is null then 0 else 1 end) as 'ML Trading',
    sum(case when p8.id is null then 0 else 1 end) as 'NMLTrading',
    sum(case when p9.id is null then 0 else 1 end) as 'Individual Custody',
    sum(case when p10.id is null then 0 else 1 end) as 'ML Individual Custody',
    sum(case when p11.id is null then 0 else 1 end) as 'Custody',
    sum(case when p12.id is null then 0 else 1 end) as 'ML Custody Trading',
    sum(case when p13.id is null then 0 else 1 end) as 'Portfolio',
    sum(case when p14.id is null then 0 else 1 end) as 'ML Personal Portfolio',
    sum(case when p15.id is null then 0 else 1 end) as Other,
    i.status
from
    (select distinct instrumentsettingsid from res_db..instrumentproducttypepermissions) p
    inner join res_db..instrumentsettings i on p.instrumentsettingsid = i.id
    left join res_db..instrumentproducttypepermissions p1 on p.instrumentsettingsid = p1.instrumentsettingsid and p1.enabled = 1 and p1.producttypeid = 1
    left join res_db..instrumentproducttypepermissions p2 on p.instrumentsettingsid = p2.instrumentsettingsid and p2.enabled = 1 and p2.producttypeid = 2
    left join res_db..instrumentproducttypepermissions p3 on p.instrumentsettingsid = p3.instrumentsettingsid and p3.enabled = 1 and p3.producttypeid = 3
    left join res_db..instrumentproducttypepermissions p4 on p.instrumentsettingsid = p4.instrumentsettingsid and p4.enabled = 1 and p4.producttypeid = 4
    left join res_db..instrumentproducttypepermissions p5 on p.instrumentsettingsid = p5.instrumentsettingsid and p5.enabled = 1 and p5.producttypeid = 5
    left join res_db..instrumentproducttypepermissions p6 on p.instrumentsettingsid = p6.instrumentsettingsid and p6.enabled = 1 and p6.producttypeid = 6
    left join res_db..instrumentproducttypepermissions p7 on p.instrumentsettingsid = p7.instrumentsettingsid and p7.enabled = 1 and p7.producttypeid = 7
    left join res_db..instrumentproducttypepermissions p8 on p.instrumentsettingsid = p8.instrumentsettingsid and p8.enabled = 1 and p8.producttypeid = 8
    left join res_db..instrumentproducttypepermissions p9 on p.instrumentsettingsid = p9.instrumentsettingsid and p9.enabled = 1 and p9.producttypeid = 9
    left join res_db..instrumentproducttypepermissions p10 on p.instrumentsettingsid = p10.instrumentsettingsid and p10.enabled = 1 and p10.producttypeid = 10
    left join res_db..instrumentproducttypepermissions p11 on p.instrumentsettingsid = p11.instrumentsettingsid and p11.enabled = 1 and p11.producttypeid = 11
    left join res_db..instrumentproducttypepermissions p12 on p.instrumentsettingsid = p12.instrumentsettingsid and p12.enabled = 1 and p12.producttypeid = 12
    left join res_db..instrumentproducttypepermissions p13 on p.instrumentsettingsid = p13.instrumentsettingsid and p13.enabled = 1 and p13.producttypeid = 13
    left join res_db..instrumentproducttypepermissions p14 on p.instrumentsettingsid = p14.instrumentsettingsid and p14.enabled = 1 and p14.producttypeid = 14
    left join res_db..instrumentproducttypepermissions p15 on p.instrumentsettingsid = p15.instrumentsettingsid and p15.enabled = 1 and p15.producttypeid = 15
    group by p.instrumentsettingsid, i.status
```

Can someone who knows about SQL please tell me (show me?) how I can make this faster/less hideous please.

Also those 15 account names are hardcoded, in a perfect world it would get the product name from the table producttypes

Sorry to ask such an annoying question.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT p.instrumentsettingsid,
         i.status,
         SUM(CASE WHEN p.producttypeid = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Cash',
         SUM(CASE WHEN p.producttypeid = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as HighInterest,
         SUM(CASE WHEN p.producttypeid = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'ML Loan',
         SUM(CASE WHEN p.producttypeid = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Investment Note',
         SUM(CASE WHEN p.producttypeid = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Trading',
         SUM(CASE WHEN p.producttypeid = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'DD Trading',
         SUM(CASE WHEN p.producttypeid = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'ML Trading',
         SUM(CASE WHEN p.producttypeid = 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'NMLTrading',
         SUM(CASE WHEN p.producttypeid = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Individual Custody',
         SUM(CASE WHEN p.producttypeid = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'ML Individual Custody',
         SUM(CASE WHEN p.producttypeid = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Custody',
         SUM(CASE WHEN p.producttypeid = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'ML Custody Trading',
         SUM(CASE WHEN p.producttypeid = 13 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Portfolio',
         SUM(CASE WHEN p.producttypeid = 14 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'ML Personal Portfolio',
         SUM(CASE WHEN p.producttypeid = 15 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Other,
    FROM res_db..instrumentproducttypepermissions p
    JOIN res_db..instrumentsettings i ON i.id = p.instrumentsettingsid
   WHERE p.enabled = 1
     AND p.producttypeid BETWEEN 1 AND 15
GROUP BY p.instrumentsettingsid, i.status
```

No need for the LEFT JOIN...

> Also those 15 account names are hardcoded, in a perfect world it would get the product name from the table producttypes

Dynamic columns requires [dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).

Comment: Morning, and how are you today?

Comment: @astander: The usual - how about you?

Comment: Good, its starting to become summer here, so nice weather. That query gave me chills to look at. You are correct, no need to join 15 times...

Comment: @astander: To be in your hemisphere - we've got high wind warning, and a possibility of snow/flurries.  Yeah, the OPs version is way overcomplicated :/

Answer (score 1):

Even using Sql Server [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) you will have to know the Column names before hand, so no luck there, unless you make use of [Pivots with Dynamic Columns](http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/andras/archive/2007/09/14/37265.aspx) or [Dynamic PIVOT](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/madhivanan/archive/2008/08/27/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server-2005.aspx)